# How to save bookmarks in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, bookmarks

I had added bookmarks to my eclipse program so that I remember to come back to those the next day. I like using bookmarks for this because I can just click on the green rectangle next to the scrollbar to quickly go to that location in my code. This is what is mean:

[image: Bookmark in eclipse]

The problem however is that once I close eclipse and reopen it, all the bookmarks are gone. They don't show green rectangle anymore. Is there a way to keep these bookmarks until I manually delete them?

Comment: Bookmarks should be preserved across sessions. They certainly are on Java files in my installation. Perhaps you should look in the .log to see if there are any messages about this.

Comment: @greg-449 How can I find the .log file and how do I understand what the messages in it will be? Sorry, I don't know much about eclipse.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message (depending on what system you use these may be hidden). If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Comment: @greg-449 For some reason the dates in the .log file are messed up. For example at the top of the document (i am guessing this is the latest), the date is `2016-02-09`. But today is the 7th Aug 2016 (the date format may be different but it still doesn't match). How can i find the messages from yesterday?

Comment: Current messages are at the end of the .log file. If there haven't been many messages the log can cover several months.

Comment: @greg-449 The the last message in the log file was on `2016-02-10 12:03:04.996`. I also checked the Date modified of the file in the .metadata folder and it was 10/02/2016. That mean there haven't been any messages since then. How else, can I solve my problem?

Comment: Are the files into which you're adding bookmarks located in the workspace? What kind of files are they? Do the bookmarks appear in the Bookmarks View?

Comment: @nitind It is a swing class and yes, it is located in the workspace. I just added a bookmark to test if it shows in the bookmarks view... It does show in the bookmarks view.

Comment: When you right-click on your swing class' source file and check the **Open With...** menu, is it the Java Editor, or something else that's opening and saving the file? And do the bookmarks survive across sessions in the Bookmarks View?

Comment: @nitind The bookmarks don't survive across session in the bookmarks view. When I added the test bookmark just now, in the Bookmarks View, it only shows that one, not the ones from yesterday.

Comment: @nitind The open with... menu the WindowBuilder Editor is already selected.

Comment: What happens to bookmarks you create when you open those files in the regular Java Editor?

Comment: @nitind I just added a **new bookmark** just now to test that. I opened the class with "Java Editor" and the Bookmark was still there.

Comment: Sounds like just a WindowBuilder bug, then.

Comment: @nitind I can confirm that with Eclipse for C++, bookmarks disappear when I restart.

Comment: The download matters less than the editor being used, Adrian.